Problem with Wording of Preliminary Set Theory Proofs
I've been through many math and computer science undergraduate books that start with preliminaries of propositional logic or set theory. I have a huge issue when it comes to 'proving' DeMorgan's laws. They inevitably break down similarly to the following:
[Passage referencing $(A \cup B)' = A' \cap B'$]

Let $x \in (A \cup B)'$. Then $x \notin A \cup B$. So $x$ is neither in $A$ nor in $B$, by the definition of the union of sets. By the definition of the complement, $x \notin A$ and $x \notin B$...

Is this not essentially restating DeMorgan's law to prove it? It also happens with virtually any basic set theory proofs. Proving commutativity of the union/intersection of two sets is an example. Restating in words what the symbols already tell us does not feel justified to me. It feels almost like they should be axioms, but many texts require students to prove them as exercises. I understand using truth tables can help, but texts focusing more on set theory and less on logic usually omit the idea of truth tables.
Is there more to it that justifies such proofs?

It is not formally circular.
It proves De Morgan laws for set operations: union and intersection, using De Morgan laws for propositions: disjunction and conjunction.
